# Android - Floating action button on top of Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, floating-action-button

I've got a `Floating Action Button` and when I click on it I open a `DialogFragment`. 
When the dialog is opened, the button is below the dialog. My question is, how do I position the button after the `onclick` event on top of the `DialogFragment`?

Comment: why do you want to do that, as re clicking the button will re-open the already opened dialog? if you really need it, or you need it to do something else, why don't you add another FAB in the created dialog

Comment: onclick event here is meant to be the same as the opening click. So, OP wants dialog to open below the button, not on top of it.

Comment: Isn't the basic definition of a dialog is that it's "modal", that is, it requires the user to interact with it or dismiss it before *anything* else?  If you don't want modality, then don't use a standard Android Dialog type solution. Make your own window instead that isn't modal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would do this trick : use Fragment and adjust it to look like dialog( you even can use dialog fragment theme ). Then use the same FAB on fragment layout ( Even better you can make transition view for fab. something like zoom out/in )... Here is the complete example uploaded on Github for you :-)

https://github.com/mabuthraa/Android-FabOverDialog

I will try later to improve that example by using Fragment theme and transition.

Good luck,'.